# End date of allDay event not rendering correctly

Tags: fullcalendar

Im using the [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io)

In the jsfiddle example below the event with `allDay:true` is not rendering correctly. it's one day short.

The date is `2017-04-15` its it renders to the `2017-04-14`

can someone help me or explain what im doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/1796/)

Comment: Read the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ -
 "end" is treated as an **exclusive** date.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks man... if read the docs but i completely read over it... if you post it as solution ill accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object - "end" is treated as an **exclusive** date.